# How to convert the & character to and using PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I convert user submitted data that contains an `&` to `and` using PHP before its stored in the database.

Comment: Converted to what? You could simply replace it with an `str_replace`, but does that solve your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$after = str_replace('&', 'and', $before);
```

Note that this will perform a straightforward replacement, hence ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4tf9T)):

```
$text = "ben & jerry, vanilla&coke";

echo str_replace('&', 'and', $text)."\n";
# ben and jerry, vanillaandcoke
```

If you want to insert spaces when there previously wasn't, then you may want to use regular expressions function like [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as follows:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s*&\s*/', ' and ', $text)."\n";
# ben and jerry, vanilla and coke
```

The pattern `\s*` is the regex pattern for ["zero or more" (`*`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [whitespace characters (`\s`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). In other words, this will replace `&`, including any preceding and following whitespaces (of any length), and replace it with `' and '`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
$str = str_replace("&", "and", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) (if your data is in a single character encoding) or [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://php.net/mb_ereg_replace) (preceded by [`mb_regex_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_regex_encoding)) otherwise.

Note, however, that `str_replace` is (in this case) safe for UTF-8.